# ActiveMQ Artemis always "Gracefully Stopping artemis-service" after start service

Tags: java, activemq-artemis

I'm installing ActiveMQ Artemis version 2.32.0 on Ubuntu 22, I created broker, created a service file in systemd:

```
[Service]
User=artemis
ExecStart=/var/lib/artemis-broker/bin/artemis-service start 
ExecStop=/var/lib/artemis-broker/bin/artemis-service stop 
Restart=on-failure
RestartSec=3s

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

But whenever I start the service, it always inform:

```
Starting artemis-service
artemis-service is now running
Gracefully Stopping artemis-service
artemis.service: Deactivated successfully.
```

Please help me. How to start ActiveMQ Artemis from systemd normally?

Comment: Is the log file created in `/var/lib/artemis-broker/log`? Do you see any error in the log before `AMQ241005`?

Comment: I checked the log file, unfortunately, I don't see any error.

Comment: Could you share in your question the log lines from AMQ241005 and AMQ221007?
Could you also confirm in you question this issue doesn't happen when you manually execute `/var/lib/artemis-broker/bin/artemis-service start`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `[service]` section you have not specified parameter `Type` which then defaults to `Type=simple`. It defines the process started with `ExecStart` as the main process of the service. Such definition is not suitable for `artemis-service` as this process ends after the broker has been started.
Add this line to your `[service]` section:

> Type=forking

This acknowledges your `ExecStart` program spawns a child process and this will be the main process of the service.